# UIViewReportBrokenSuperviewChain

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, avfoundation

Application get crashed for barcode scanning using AVFoundation. 
following is my code.

```
_session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    _device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error = nil;

    _input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_device error:&error];
    if (_input) {
        [_session addInput:_input];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }

    _output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
    [_output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_session addOutput:_output];

    _output.metadataObjectTypes = [_output availableMetadataObjectTypes];

    _prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
    _prevLayer.frame = _previewView.bounds;

    _prevLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    //[self.view.layer addSublayer:_prevLayer];
    [_previewView.layer addSublayer:_prevLayer];
      //[self.view];
    //[_session startRunning];

    [_previewView bringSubviewToFront:_highlightView];
```

/* code Ends*/

Showing Bad Access.

Comment: is there a backtrace?

Answer (score 0):

```
[_previewView.layer addSublayer:_prevLayer];
```

This line occurs after the frame is set. Try adding the layer and then setting the frame. I'm sure you've moved on, but this answer could benefit someone else.